# Is there anyway to compute the CEV-implied volatility from option prices?

Tags: volatility, black-scholes, implied-volatility

Under Black-Scholes, there exists a solution for the option price for a volatility. The volatility can then be backed out from the option price using numeric methods.

For the constant-elasticity of volatility model (CEV), there isn't a closed form solution for the price as a function of vol; it has to be calculated using the chi-squared distribution. If I want to get the "CEV-implied volatility", it would be very slow for me to use this numeric method as part of another numeric method. Is there any work on this?